# Java WebSphere server stop randomly when debugging in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, server, websphere

I'm running a Java server and it works fine by now but recently it stops sometimes when I'm debugging my code. I don't know if the problem is due to java class is using many request/response API or it can be something else.

Have you got any ideas or met this issue before?

Best regards

Comment: Try to find the logs/crash dumps from the server and add them to your question, otherwise it's impossible to tell what's wrong.

Comment: The WebSphere server has a system property you can enable to help debug unexplained shutdowns - set "-Dcom.ibm.ws.runtime.dumpShutdown=true" as a generic JVM argument.  It will throw a stack dump to SystemErr.log when the server stop method is called and when the server's JVM shutdown hook is called.

Comment: Also, is your code calling System.exit(), perchance?  If so... that call applies to the JVM as a whole, and calling it from an app will actually kill your entire server.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I reset logs before server starts but when I wrote this question it seems problem dissapears.